# OppId need to be populated on case

Tags: trigger, workflow

When an Opportunity of Record Type='Execute' is closed 
a) Case of Record Type ='order management' should be created, routed to OM queue and OppId need to be populated on case.

b) When OM member close queue, Email has to be send.

Can I make it like this with workflow? or trigger?

1. Setup >> Create >> Workflows & Approvals >> Workflow Rules >> New Rule >> Opportunity
2. Evaluate the workflow "created, and every time it’s edited"
3. Run the rule if the following "formula evaluates to true"
4. Formula is this: ISPICKVAL(Execute, "Closed")
   but how to do it with case or to write trigger and how can I send the email template with workflow or trigger.

Comment: Have you tried anything?   You'll get a better response if you edit your question with actual code or process builder flows as the Community tends not to like doing your work for you.

Comment: Can I make it with trigger or workflow like this  Setup >> Create >> Workflows & Approvals >> Workflow Rules >> New Rule >> Opportunity
Evaluate the workflow "created, and every time it’s edited"
Run the rule if the following "formula evaluates to true"
4. Formula is this:
ISPICKVAL(Execute, "Closed")
5. Add a field update that changes the record type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use Process Builder or a Trigger as a Workflow rule is not able to create a new Case record only update a field or send an email.  Process Builder or a Trigger can both create the case record and send an email if required. This can auto assign that new case to the queue or you can use an assignment rule.

I would recommend using Process Builder in the first place as it is easier to use than writing Apex Code and allows you to prototype the logic even if you decide a trigger is required.

[image: an example]

If the Case is accepted from the Queue and then closed a workflow rule can easily be setup to send an email. In this case I would advise including the Record Type in the Formula as it will prevent emails being sent on other cases when closed.